# Windows Application hanging

Tags: c#, button

I create a Windows Form Application with C#. The form has five `Button`. I add a library `SharpDX.XInput` to get XBox Joy Sticker. When I press XBox's DPad, the Button will set border to 5 and 0 marking as selection. When I use **Alt+Tab** to change to other application and wait some minutes and go back to the Application, pressing DPad will cause the Application hanging.

C# Code

```
private void SetSelect(Button previous, Button current)
{
    previous.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    current.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 5;
}
```

I use TaskManager to dump file.

```
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()
KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Internal.GPStream.Read(System.IntPtr buf = {System.IntPtr}, int length = 427071)
[Native to Managed Transition]  
GdiPlus.dll!DuplicateStream(struct IStream *,struct IStream * *)
GdiPlus.dll!GpWicPngDecoder::InitDecoder(struct IStream *,enum DecoderInitFlag)
GdiPlus.dll!CreateDecoderForStream(struct IStream *,struct IImageDecoder * *,enum DecoderInitFlag)  
GdiPlus.dll!GpDecodedImage::GpDecodedImage(struct IStream *)
GdiPlus.dll!GpDecodedImage::CreateFromStream()
GdiPlus.dll!CopyOnWriteBitmap::DereferenceStream()
GdiPlus.dll!CopyOnWriteBitmap::CopyOnWriteBitmap()
GdiPlus.dll!CopyOnWriteBitmap::Clone()
GdiPlus.dll!GpBitmap::Clone()
GdiPlus.dll!GpTexture::InitializeBrushBitmap()
GdiPlus.dll!GpTexture::InitializeBrush()
GdiPlus.dll!GpTexture::GpTexture(class GpImage *,enum WrapMode,int)
GdiPlus.dll!GdipCreateTexture()
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.TextureBrush.TextureBrush(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode wrapMode)
```

The application was hanged in `WaitForSingleObject()`.
Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this issue??

Comment: I think it's better to use `async` and `await` ?

Comment: Why do you need WaitForSingleObject().?  Your form project is waiting for the other application to complete.  If the two apps are running in parallel than you do not need to wait.

Comment: I don't use any WaitForSingleObject. I just update Button's border width. Then the application was hanging. I use taskmanager to dump file and open with Visual Studio to see CallStack. The last call function is WaitForSingleObject.